# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') vuex**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import post from './modules/post'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    

    modules: {
        post
    }
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODcF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have version problem in your `VueX` which is under version 4. Try to uninstall and add version 4

```
npm uninstall vuex

npm i vuex@4.0.0
```

Comment: Why is alpha recommended?

Comment: I just checked version from my current package.json of project, normal one would work as well. I am editing @EstusFlask